# Website images not updating

Tags: html, image, web

The images on my website aren't updating. I have even deleted the image and it still shows as it's there. I'm on Google Chrome. I've cleared my cookies, cached files and images, and flushed my DNS through CMD but the image is still there.

http://prntscr.com/49yqwi - CSS.png is displaying here.

http://prntscr.com/49yr0s - CSS.png is not on my cPanel after I have deleted it. I've refreshed, logged out and back in, etc.

How can I get this image to update?

CODE:

```
<div class="Course">
    <p class="tutorial">CSS</p>
    <img src="CSS.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the physical code to make it easier for us to edit?

Comment: did you sure that the image have name css.png?? from the page you given the image have name as  `PBw1Mun.png`.

Answer (score 6):

It was cloudflare's DNS holding onto it. I fixed this issue by logging into cloudflare and selecting "Purge Cache".

Comment: The "Purge everything" didn't do the trick for me. What I had to do was purge the individual images, file by file, then get Chrome to re-cache them by opening the file URL and refreshing. Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely sure you deleted all reference to the image then try hard refreshing chrome http://www.code-pal.com/quick-tip-clear-cache-hard-refresh-on-chrome/

Comment: This still didn't work, but I am 100% sure I have deleted the image from my host. Could it be cloudflare DNS holding onto it?

Comment: I am not sure, Did you try different browsers or different computers? to see if it is a local issue?

Answer (score -1):

Did you delete the image from your server or from the server of i.imgur.com ?

The source of your image is not the native URL so I suppose the mistake is the including of the image.

The source is this link: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEGh4.png

Comment: No, that's a screenshot OF the website. Not of the image that was uploaded. It is not an imgur link.